# Создание HMACSHA1 из сообщения в Tls v1.0

Tags: c#, ssl, tls

Здравствуйте. Нужна помощь в создании HMACSHA1, я использую версию TLS v.`1.0`, CipherSuite - `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x0035)`.

Я пытаюсь проверить то, что прислал сервер. (`Handshake`). 

Сообщение я смог сверить (совпало с тем, что высчитал сервер), а создать HMACSHA1, к сожалению не получается.
Получаю все ключи данным способом:

```
byte[] pre_master_secret = Program.PrivateKey.Decrypt(CKE_pubkKey, RSAEncryptionPadding.Pkcs1);
byte[] master_secret = TlsUtilities.PRF_legacy(pre_master_secret, "master secret", ByteArray.Concat(ClientRandomBytes, ServerRandomBytes), 48);
byte[] key_block = TlsUtilities.PRF_legacy(master_secret, "key expansion", ByteArray.Concat(ServerRandomBytes, ClientRandomBytes), 136);

byte[] client_write_mac = new byte[20]; 
byte[] server_write_mac = new byte[20];

byte[] client_write_key = new byte[32];
byte[] server_write_key = new byte[32];

byte[] client_write_iv = new byte[16];
byte[] server_write_iv = new byte[16];


Buffer.BlockCopy(key_block, 0, client_write_mac, 0, 20);
Buffer.BlockCopy(key_block, 20, server_write_mac, 0, 20);
//40
Buffer.BlockCopy(key_block, 40, client_write_key, 0, 32);
Buffer.BlockCopy(key_block, 72, server_write_key, 0, 32);
//104
Buffer.BlockCopy(key_block, 104, client_write_iv, 0, 16);
Buffer.BlockCopy(key_block, 120, server_write_iv, 0, 16);
```

`(20 bytes)client_write_mac: d1b7e17789ff5d7e7bd6bca8c7caf45eb27cd5ea`

Хэш, полученный по формуле:

```
byte[] FinishHash = TlsUtilities.PRF_legacy(master_secret,"client finished",ByteArray.Concat(md5.ComputeHash(Tools.HexToBytes(Hash)), sha.ComputeHash(Tools.HexToBytes(Hash))),12);
```

Сообщение (hash) (HEX):`75be1066597877c56c600362`
 Совпадает с тем, что прислал клиент, а полученный мною HMACSHA1 нет. HMACSHA1 составляю так: `0000000000000000160301000c75be1066597877c56c600362`, ключ для HMACSHA1 указывается: `client_write_key`
HMAC, получаемый от клиента: `9b7203938a4502645c8a23c04dc5d48b968a2d31`
HMAC, генерируемый сервером: `a2772a62204a030c72621d8f80c87d724402d227`

Прошу помочь мне!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны считать MAC от сообщения вместе с заголовками, то есть от:

```
000000000000000016030100101400000c75be1066597877c56c600362
```

Здесь:

```
0000000000000000 - seq num
16 - handshake
0301 - version
0010 - длина сообщения с заголовками
14 - finished
00000c - длина сообщения
75be1066597877c56c600362 - сообщение
```